# Failed to start Apache HTTP server

Tags: apache2

I did, sudo systemctl status apache2, and this is the reply...

```
apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2021-11-18 21:55:22 EST; 3h 42min ago
       Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/

Nov 18 21:55:20 T540p systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Nov 18 21:55:22 T540p apachectl[973]: [Thu Nov 18 21:55:22.715512 2021] [core:warn] [pid 973] AH00111:>
Nov 18 21:55:22 T540p apachectl[973]: apache2: Syntax error on line 80 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: D>
Nov 18 21:55:22 T540p apachectl[941]: Action 'start' failed.
Nov 18 21:55:22 T540p apachectl[941]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Nov 18 21:55:22 T540p systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILU>
Nov 18 21:55:22 T540p systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 18 21:55:22 T540p systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

I went to /etc/apache2/apache2.conf to check line 80, and seems nothing wrong in there.
Also did try  reload apache2.  and I got this reply... apache2.service is not active, cannot reload.

I don't want to re-install the OS because I have dual boot.
Any help would greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you edit your question and post the line 80 (and surrounding, if possible).  Besides, the line with error is truncated.  Could you provide the full line?

Comment: As the error message says, there may be something specific in `/var/log/apache2/error.log` that explains what the problem is on line 80 (or thereabouts) 

Comment: Thanks Marc and matigo!  Sorry, for the late reply. I went to the /var/log/apache2/error.log but the file is empty.   If I can't solved this, I might reinstall ubuntu.  Thanks guys!